# Sets huskylens modes

Tags: arduino, i2c

I want to use the Huskylens for both follow-line and tracking objects functionality.

Does anyone know how to change the Huskylens camera mode via code with Arduino? Every answer will be appreciated.

I tried to search for info and found nothing.